# rselenium clicking on dropdown element to collect data

Tags: r, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to collect some area names from a website and in order to do so I want to click the drop-down box to expand the downwards pointing arrow.

i.e. on the following page if I click on the "distritos" drop down I can see further drop down-availability

```
https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/todas-las-zonas/l
```

For `Ciutat Vella` I see I have 4 additional items `Barri Gòtic`, `EL Raval`, `La Barceloneta` and `Sant Pare, Sta...`

I would like to collect these names also. I have the following code to collect the following:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

# 1.a) Open URL, click on provincias
rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4536L)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

url2 = "https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/todas-las-zonas/l"
remDr$navigate(url2)
remDr$maxWindowSize()
# accept cookies
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/footer/div/button[2]')$clickElement()
#click on Distrito
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div')$clickElement()
html_distrito_full_page = remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html()


Distritos_Names = html_distrito_full_page %>% 
  html_nodes('.re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem') %>% 
  html_nodes('.re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal') %>% 
  html_text()
Distritos_Names
```

Which gives:

```
 [1] "Ciutat Vella"          "Eixample"              "Gràcia"                "Horta - Guinardó"      "Les Corts"             "Nou Barris"            "Sant Andreu"           "Sant Martí"           
 [9] "Sants - Montjuïc"      "Sarrià - Sant Gervasi"
```

However, this is missing the names of the regions in the drop-down boxes.

How can I collect these drop-down links also? i.e. `RSelenium` to navigate to the page, expand all "downwards facing arrows" then use `rvest` to scrape the whole page once these downwards facing arrows have been expanded.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use rvest to get the mappings by extracting the JavaScript variable housing the mappings + some other data. Use jsonlite to deserialize the extracted string into a JSON object, then apply a custom function to extract the actual mappings for each dropdown. Wrap that function in a map_dfr() call to get a final combined dataframe of all dropdown mappings.

---

TODO: Review JSON to see if can remove magic number 4 and dynamically determine the correct item to retrieve from parent list.

---

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)

extract_data <- function(x) {
  tibble(
    location = x$literal,
    sub_location = map(x$subLocations, "literal", pluck)
  )
}

p <- read_html("https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/todas-las-zonas/l") %>% html_text()
s <- str_match(p, 'window\\.__INITIAL_PROPS__ = JSON\\.parse\\("(.*)"')[, 2]
data <- jsonlite::parse_json(gsub('\\\\\\"', '\\\"', gsub('\\\\"', '"', s)))
location_data <- data$initialSearch$result$geographicSearch[4]
df <- map_dfr(location_data, extract_data)
```